# Move semantics and return values

Tags: c++11, return-value, move

Are the `std::move` at the end of the following function needed (to avoid copying the vectors)?

```
std::pair<vector<int>, vector<int>> f()
{
    vector<int> a, b;
    ...
    return std::make_pair(std::move(a), std::move(b));
}
```

Or will the compiler move the vectors even if the `std::move` are omitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::move`s are necessary.

If what you suggest were allowed, the following code would be (surprisingly) broken since both arguments to `std::make_pair` would be moved-from:

```
std::vector<int> a;
// populate a
return std::make_pair(a, a);
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer!